# How to insert hyphen "-" after 2 digits automatically in TextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have one TextBox for user to input number.

When user input to the TextBox then the format should be like this

> 01-22-34-40-33

I want to insert "-" after 2 digits in the TextChanged event handler.

I do something like this but no work:

```
if(txtRandomThirdTypeSales.Text.Length == 2)
{
    txtRandomThirdTypeSales.Text += "-";
}
else if (txtRandomThirdTypeSales.Text.Length == 5)
{
    txtRandomThirdTypeSales.Text += "-";        
}
else if (txtRandomThirdTypeSales.Text.Length == 8)
{
    txtRandomThirdTypeSales.Text += "-";        
}
else if (txtRandomThirdTypeSales.Text.Length == 11)
{
    txtRandomThirdTypeSales.Text += "-";
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not work"? did you put some break points to see what is going on?

Comment: I mean, if there are more than what is the condition does then no function!

Comment: Please try my answer and share the status

Comment: try chaging in the on `KeyDown` event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you please try this way,this may be will helpful for you.

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        string sVal = textBox1.Text;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sVal) && e.KeyCode != Keys.Back)
        {
            sVal = sVal.Replace("-", "");
            string newst = Regex.Replace(sVal, ".{2}", "$0-");
            textBox1.Text = newst;
            textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
        }
    }
```

Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: why do you want to use Regex for a such a simple requirement ?

Comment: Work great, how to accept the backspace delete event if there any mistake ?

Comment: I have update code I have change "textBox1_KeyPress" event to  "textBox1_KeyDown" and add this conditon "e.KeyCode != Keys.Back" for backspace delete event if any mistake.

Comment: You code was solved my problem, but there is another question how do I compare each value?

Comment: I added `&& e.KeyCode != Keys.Delete` to allow the user to select portions of text and press delete.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this

```
if(txtRandomThirdTypeSales.Text.Count(x => x != '-') % 2 == 0)
{
    txtRandomThirdTypeSales.Text += "-";
}
```

That way it counts all the chars that are not a `-` and checks if they are even. If they are, add the '-'.

You can make it more restrictive by checking that they are digits with a regex. `^\d`

Comment: What would happen if someone wants to delete the last "-"? Like pressing backspace with "12-"?

Comment: I tried you condition but it seem got an error after type 2 digits number...!

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try this

```
if(txtRandomThirdTypeSales.Text.Length % 3 == 2)
{
    txtRandomThirdTypeSales.Text += "-";
}
```

You can also add code to handle backspace key down and delete key down.

Comment: I tried your condition it works great, but the cursor jump to the beginning of the textbox how can the cursor should be on the last input?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried TextBox masking? it is available in Winform controls

Here is your reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx

Comment: I used try that but Textbox Masking is a static format, or is there anyway to do it in dynamic format?

Comment: I see, the number that you are trying to mask, is it of fixed length?

Comment: Nope, it is a dynamic length! it doesn't matter how many digits user input to the textbox.