# Guidance text when typing in a text box in c#

Tags: c#, text

I'm a starter at this so not sure if this is simple or crazly hard but what i would like is after 6 characters in a text box a - to appear and then they continue typing abit like when you do a license number in windows and it autopolutes the field as you go.

Comment: Perhaps add an image to clarify what you want? Also, WinForms, WPF, or some other framework?

Comment: winforms. Text Field.using visual Studio. (sorry very new to this)

Comment: Does Windows do that, or does it just have separate text boxes for each block, and auto-jump the cursor from one to the next as necessary?  That might be easier to accomplish...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert hyphen "-" after 2 digits automatically in TextBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28038145/how-to-insert-hyphen-after-2-digits-automatically-in-textbox)

Comment: can you show what you have tried so far? everything is possible in coding, it can be done, in this case with events

Comment: Note that there's also a [MaskedTextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) that allows you to define the input you want and show things like hyphens, etc., where they should be.  Might make your life easier!

Comment: if(txtRandomThirdTypeSales.Text.Count(x => x != '-') % 2 == 0)
{
    txtRandomThirdTypeSales.Text += "-";
}    ...but this just errors

Answer (score 0):

Add an event KeyPress to your textbox, so every time when you change text it will add '-' if needed. Something like this:

```
private void textBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) == false)
    {
        var tb = (sender as TextBox);
        var text = tb.Text;
        var blocks = text.Split('-');
        var lastBlock = blocks.Last();
        if (lastBlock.Length == 6)
        {
            tb.Text += "-";
            tb.SelectionStart = tb.Text.Length;
        }
    }
}
```

There is a bug although with entering '-', as it is used as a separator.

Comment: (Note: if you use an `as` cast, *always* check for `null`. If you don't expect the cast to fail, use a normal case)

Comment: You ought to consider what to do when the user tries a backspace after the sixth character

Comment: @lan agree. Then change it to KeyPressed event and check what key was actually pressed.

Comment: if(txtRandomThirdTypeSales.Text.Count(x => x != '-') % 2 == 0)
{
    txtRandomThirdTypeSales.Text += "-";
}

Comment: @MatthewRodwell what kind of error? what you were typing? I get no errors for now